# CakePHP views question

Tags: cakephp, view

I am working on a project using CakePHP and have been trying to update some views. The file uploads to the server correctly but the system seems to serve the old version. I am kind of new to Cake so I'd appreciate any pointers.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I experienced the same thing.  The trick is to clear out all of `$YOUR_APP_FOLDER/tmp/cache` when deploying new code, to erase any conflicting cache.

```
cd $YOUR_APP_FOLDER
rm -f tmp/cache/*/*
```

Answer (score 1):

It could be that [view-caching](http://book.cakephp.org/view/325/View-Caching) is enabled, check core.php for

```
define ('CACHE_CHECK', true);
```

Answer (score 1):

Where are you putting the views? Also, make sure the `/tmp/cache/` folder doesn't have any lingering crap in it that might be getting rendered.

**Edit**:

If you set the debug level in `config/core.php` to something higher than 0, caching will be disabled and you'll get nice error messages if something poops the bed.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to ignore cache of views is uncommenting

```
Configure::write('Cache.disable', true);
```

in core.php